# Recorrer todas las hojas de un excel - Con JAVA y POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Buen día, tengo una funcionalidad que reemplaza el texto de unas celdas en un documento Excel, hasta el momento funciona, pero me encontré con un problema, cuando son archivos excel que tienen más de una hoja por libro, solo recorre la primera hoja y reemplaza, las otras hojas no las recorre ni nada, si pudieran ayudarme, he estado buscando pero solo aparece para recorrer una hoja, pero no dicen como hacer que recorra una especifica o algo así.

El código que recorre el archivo xlsx (solo la primera hoja) es este:

```
public static void XLSX(String Ubicacion) throws IOException {

        Ubicacion = Ubicacion.replace("\\", "/"); //Convierto todos los \ en / para congruir en direcciones
        try {
            File Fil = new File(Ubicacion); //Se crea un archivo File
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Fil); //Se crea archivo FileInput para la lectura
            // Crear el objeto que tendra el libro de Excel
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            /*
         * Obtenemos la primera pestaña a la que se quiera procesar indicando el indice.
         * Una vez obtenida la hoja excel con las filas que se quieren leer obtenemos el iterator
         * que nos permite recorrer cada una de las filas que contiene.
             */
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            Row row;
            // Recorremos todas las filas para mostrar el contenido de cada celda
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                // Obtenemos el iterator que permite recorres todas las celdas de una fila
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                Cell celda;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    celda = cellIterator.next();
                    // Dependiendo del formato de la celda el valor se debe mostrar como String, Fecha, boolean, entero...
                    switch (celda.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(celda)) {
                                // System.out.println(celda.getDateCellValue());
                            } else {
                                //System.out.println(celda.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            String item = "";
                            item = celda.getStringCellValue(); //Tomamos el valor de la celda
                            if (item.startsWith("<") && item.endsWith(">")) { //validamos que el contenido de la celda comience por < y termine en >
                                item = item.toLowerCase(); //Hago todo el item en minuscula
                                item = item.replace(">", "");
                                item = item.replace("<", "");
                                System.out.println("ITEM: "+item);
                                Merge(celda, item); //enviamos donde se le cambiará el item por el valor
                            }
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            System.out.println(celda.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // cerramos el libro excel
            file.close();
            //Se genera el nuevo archivo con los datos cambiados
            NewDocumento = "A01_" + "MergeFULL_" + document1 + "_SASPRUEBA_XLSX" + type1; //Creamos el nombre del documento
            NewDocumento = ruta1 + NewDocumento; //Agregamos el nombre del documento a la ruta donde se almacena
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(NewDocumento); //Doy la ruta y el nombre del archivo nuevo que se generará
            workbook.write(fileOut); //Escribo el nuevo archivo
            fileOut.close(); //Cierro el archivo

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

En el Método Merge es donde hago el reemplazo del contenido donde encuentro los items que necesito:

```
public static void Merge(Cell cell, String item) {
        if (item.equals("item1")) {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Fabian Montoya");
        } else if (item.equals("item3")) {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Excel_GO");
        } else {
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("Item_not_found");
        }
    }
```

Pero como les digo, solo recorre la primera hoja, en documentos con más hojas no las recorre, solo lo hace en la primera, si por favor pudiera ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho.

Librerias, uso las POI

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, era más facil de lo que creia, les dejo el código donde hago el recorrido, lo otro ya lo tienen :)

```
public static void XLSX(String Ubicacion) throws IOException {

        Ubicacion = Ubicacion.replace("\\", "/"); //Convierto todos los \ en / para congruir en direcciones
        try {
            File Fil = new File(Ubicacion); //Se crea un archivo File
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Fil); //Se crea archivo FileInput para la lectura
            // Crear el objeto que tendra el libro de Excel
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            /*
         * Obtenemos la primera pestaña a la que se quiera procesar indicando el indice.
         * Una vez obtenida la hoja excel con las filas que se quieren leer obtenemos el iterator
         * que nos permite recorrer cada una de las filas que contiene.
             */

            Hojas = workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); //Obtenemos el número de hojas que contiene el documento
            System.out.println("Número Hojas: "+Hojas);

            //For que recorre las hojas existentes
            for (int i = 0; i < Hojas; i++) {                
                System.out.println("Hoja #: "+i+" - Nombre: "+workbook.getSheetName(i)); //Muestra la hoja en la estamos y el nombre de esta
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i); //Seleccionamos la hoja que vamos a recorrer
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                Row row;
                // Recorremos todas las filas para mostrar el contenido de cada celda
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    row = rowIterator.next();
                    // Obtenemos el iterator que permite recorres todas las celdas de una fila
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    Cell celda;
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        celda = cellIterator.next();
                        // Dependiendo del formato de la celda el valor se debe mostrar como String, Fecha, boolean, entero...
                        switch (celda.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(celda)) {
                                    // System.out.println(celda.getDateCellValue());
                                } else {
                                    //System.out.println(celda.getNumericCellValue());
                                }
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                String item = "";
                                item = celda.getStringCellValue(); //Tomamos el valor de la celda
                                if (item.startsWith("<") && item.endsWith(">")) { //validamos que el contenido de la celda comience por < y termine en >
                                    item = item.toLowerCase(); //Hago todo el item en minuscula
                                    item = item.replace(">", "");
                                    item = item.replace("<", "");
                                    System.out.println("ITEM: " + item);
                                    Merge(celda, item); //enviamos donde se le cambiará el item por el valor
                                }
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                System.out.println(celda.getBooleanCellValue());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // cerramos el libro excel
            file.close();
            //Se genera el nuevo archivo con los datos cambiados
            NewDocumento = "A01_" + "MergeFULL_" + document1 + "_SASPRUEBA_XLSX" + type1; //Creamos el nombre del documento
            NewDocumento = ruta1 + NewDocumento; //Agregamos el nombre del documento a la ruta donde se almacena
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(NewDocumento); //Doy la ruta y el nombre del archivo nuevo que se generará
            workbook.write(fileOut); //Escribo el nuevo archivo
            fileOut.close(); //Cierro el archivo

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex);
        }
```